# How to Cache Elements in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, caching, sdk

I wrote a RSS based application that will fetch some XML files, parse them and throw them into a table view.

I'm using the NSURLConnection and the NSXMLParser in order to connect and parse the XML content.

I would like to cache those results so that once the user connected once to the application he could disconnect and view the content, offline.

Is there any API that handles that? or do I need to save my dataObjects (which hold the parsed XML data) inside a NSFileManager and retrieve it each time I load my application?

Code snippets, examples or any document will be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the OP wants to know about, how to serialize data for his RSS Feed reader. You can try using SQLite or Core Data. SQLite is easy to program. But you should be careful in implementing concurrency yourself. NSOperationQueue could help you out.

Comment: This is what I was looking for -  serializing my data.
I use the NSURLCache to see if i already visited a feed, now I can use the Core Data or even a NSDictonary (with write to file) in order to retrieve the data.